# iOS ARC: unexpected 'dealloc' call

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a problem with an Objective-C class, when ARC is enabled.

My classes looks like these:

```
@interface ParentClass : NSObject {
}

-(void)decodeMethod;
@end

@implementation ParentClass

-(void)decodeMethod{
}

@end

@interface ChilldClass : ParentClass{
  int *buffer;
}
@end

@implementation ChildClass

-(id)init{
  self = [super init];

  if(self != nil){
    buffer = (int *)malloc(20*sizeof(int));
  }

  return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
  free(buffer);
}

@end
```

I have another class like this one:

```
@interface OtherClass : NSObject{
  ParentClass *c;
}
@end

@implementation OtherClass

[...]

-(void)decode{
  c = [[ChildClass alloc] init];

  [c decodeMethod];
}

[...]

@end
```

As you can see, a `ChildClass` object is created and stored as an attribute in `OtherClass`. As long as the `OtherClass` object is living, the `ChildClass` object pointed by `c` should be also living, isn't it? Well, I have a **BAD_ACCESS error**, because after the `ChildClass` initialization, and before the `decodeMethod` is called, the `dealloc` method in `ChildClass` is automatically executed.

Why? `ARC` is enabled, so the `dealloc` method should be called automatically when the `ChildClass` object is released, but it shouldn't happen in this moment, because is still pointed with `c`.

Any help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How does `decodeMethod` in `ParentClass` access the ivar in its subclass???

Comment: How do you create the instance of `OtherClass`?

Comment: What's in the `init` of `ParentClass`? Can there be a `[self release]`?

Comment: It doesn't matter how I create the OtherClass object, because I'm calling the ivar inside a method of this class, so the OtherClass object is living for sure.

In the ParentClass' init method there's nothing. A self release is forbidden because I'm using ARC.

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface ChilldClass : ParentClass{
```

It's possible your issue is caused by a spelling error in `ChilldClass` (typo?)

Comment: No, there's not any typo. Thank you!